# Need to create class Route and Point

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm struggling with this easy assignment. I need to create 2 classes, Point and Route. I need to add/remove Points to/from Route and then calculate the sum distance between the Points in the Route.

So far my code is this:

```
import math

class Point:
    "Two-dimensional points"

    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def __str__(self):
        result = "\n".join(["x: %f" % self.x(),
                            "y: %f" % self.y(),
                            "rho: %f" % self.rho(),
                            "theta: %f" % self.theta()])
        return result

# Queries

    def x(self):
        "Abscissa"
        return self._x

    def y(self):
        "Ordinate"
        return self._y

    def rho(self):
        "Distance to origin (0, 0)"
        return math.sqrt(self.x()**2 + self.y()**2)

    def theta(self):
        "Angle to horizontal axis"
        return math.atan2(self.y(), self.x())

    def distance(self, other):
        "Distance to other"
        return self.vectorTo(other).rho()

    def vectorTo(self, other):
        "Returns the Point representing the vector from self to other Point"
        return Point(other.x() - self.x(), other.y() - self.y())

# Commands

    def translate(self, dx, dy):
        "Move by dx horizontally, dy vertically"
        self._x += dx
        self._y += dy

    def scale(self, factor):
        "Scale by factor"
        self._x *= factor
        self._y *= factor

    def centre_rotate(self, angle):
        "Rotate around origin (0, 0) by angle"
        temp_x = self.rho() * math.cos(self.theta() + angle)
        temp_y = self.rho() * math.sin(self.theta() + angle)
        self._x, self._y = temp_x, temp_y

    def rotate(self, p, angle):
        "Rotate around p by angle"
        self.translate(-p.x(), -p.y())
        self.centre_rotate(angle)
        self.translate(p.x(), p.y())

class Route:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Point = []


    def __add__ (x,y,index):
        self.points.insert(Point(x,y), index)
```

The Point works fine but I can't figure out how to get Route to work.

The error I get is:

```
>>> 
>>> route = Route()
>>> route.add(32, 12, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    route.add(32, 12, 2)
  File "C:\Users\John Wayne\Dropbox\kool\geom.py", line 73, in add
    self.points.insert(Point(x, y), index)
TypeError: 'Point' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>
```

OK I have managed to fix the Route class as following:

```
class Route:
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = []


    def add_point(self, x, y, index):
        self.points.insert(index, Point(x,y))
```

But now I have problem with my method get_lenght:

```
 def get_lenght(self, Point):
  for Point in self.points:
```

What is wrong with this get_lenght method?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is your `Route()` class?

Comment: Its right at the end:
`code`
class Route:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Point = []


    def __add__ (x,y,index):
        self.points.insert(Point(x,y), index)

Comment: You did not include your class? What does `self.points.insert()` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to insert in to the list self.points using the insert method.  Insert takes two arguments:

```
my_list = []
my_list.insert(index, object)
```

Which will insert the object before the index supplied.  The argument 'index' must be a number.

In your example, you have passed the object first and the index second.  Switch the arguments around and it should be working fine. e.g.:
    self.points.insert(index, Point(x,y))

Alternatively, if you just want to add the object on to the end of the list, the 'append' method may work better for you:

```
self.points.append(Point(x,y))
```

In addition, I have assumed that your class 'Route' is written as follows as the code copied above appears to be incorrect (your method 'add' shouldn't be defined with the underscored before and after, you didn't pass 'self' as the first argument to your add method, and you had inconsistency with self.points):

```
class Route:
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = []


    def add (self, x, y, index):
        self.points.insert(Point(x,y), index)
```

Comment: OK I have managed to fix the Route class as following:

    class Route:
        def __init__(self):
            self.points = []
            
            
        def add_point(self, x, y, index):
            self.points.insert(index, Point(x,y))

But now I have problem with my method get_lenght:

     def get_lenght(self, Point):
      for Point in self.points:

What is wrong with this get_lenght method?

Thank you very much.

Comment: For the future, instead of saying "i have a problem" i'd advise saying what you did and exactly what exception you are getting, however if you are trying to get the length of the list, use: 
    def get_length(self, Point):
        return len(self.points)

Comment: However for my answer above you don't need to send Point in to the method... but you haven't fully explained what you want the get_length method to do, maybe my assumption about what you meant was wrong...

Comment: I need to get the distance between 2 Points that are included in the Route.

For example:
>>> route = Route()
>>> route.add_point(3, 32, 21)
>>> route.add_point(3, 34, 32)
>>> route.get_lenght() I need to calculate the distance between the fist and second Point in the Route list. I hope I explain it clear enough

Comment: I think that is best opened as a new question with a copy of the code you have tried and the exception you are getting.  It's a bit tricky working with code within comments.